AWS policy statement to allow user to create role that trust cloudtrail.amazonaws.com to assume
I want to implement a policy for SRE that enable them to create/delete roles with names prefixed by trail*, and these roles should only be trusted by CloudTrail.
This means SREs should not be able to create or delete roles that trust anything other than CloudTrail. To illustrate this requirement more precisely, the trusted entity of the role should be defined as follows:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

My policy statement is as follows:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/trail*",
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/trail*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": [
                        "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/service-role/Cloudtrail-CW-access-policy-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

However, even after creating and attaching this policy to sre, they are still unable to delete trail22(Role Name). The error message received is:
Failed deleting role trail22.
User: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/sre is not authorized to perform: iam:DetachRolePolicy on resource: role trail22 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:DetachRolePolicy action


Your use of sts:AWSServiceName in the policy condition is what's causing this afaik. It relates to the principal that's actually making the iam:DetachRolePolicy request and that's an IAM user in this case, not the CloudTrail service. The condition doesn't relate to the configured trusted entity.

I'm not aware of any way to do exactly what you want. Also see somewhat related question here.
